# unable to get local issuer certificate httpd

Tags: ios, apache, ipad, ssl, httpd.conf

I have httpd server configured with SSL option. I am trying to access my server using iPad.

When I use safari browser it works fine. But when I try to access URL from my ios app,it gives following error in httpd server.

[Tue May 10 12:23:00.315602 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 10236:tid 46970516982080] [client x.x.x.x:64866] AH02276: Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate

[Tue May 10 12:23:00.315684 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 10236:tid 46970516982080] [client x.x.x.x:64866] AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?

I want to know if it is something to do with my ios app settings?

Can anyone please explain why it is working fine with Safari browser inside iPad?

Comment: Is the iOS app an app that you wrote yourself and you are try to test locally or a third party downloaded app? If you wrote the app then your code is probably not handling the handshake properly. The browser code is handling the handshake properly.

Comment: I am using thirdparty downloaded app. Yes, most probably it is iOS app who is culprit. But how to check that? Other browsers like Firefox & Chrome installed in iPad also not able to connect. Do I need to perform any specific steps to make them work?

Comment: Can you help me understand why a third party iOS app (that is not a browser) would point itself at your private server?